# Not recognizing JARs using Apache-Pig on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

My goal is to use spatial functionality in my pig-scripts with pigeon. To use the pigeon-functions I register three JARs (pigeon-0.2.1.jar, esri-geometry-api-1.2.1.jar and jts-1.8.jar) at the beginning, which runs without errors and warnings.
When I run pig commands in the pig command line (grunt) everything is fine (except some deprication warnings, but refering to other posts this can be ignorned) but as soon as I want to run a pigeon command like ST_MakePoint an error comes up:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve ST_MakePoint using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

I am using: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, Hadoop 2.7.1 (singlenode), pig 0.15.0

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: What is ST_makepoint ? Is it a class name or package name?

Comment: Sorry. ST_MakePoint is a function in the pigeon-jar. And what I do is
    points = LOAD 'trajectory.tsv' AS (time: datetime, lat:double, lon:double);
s_points = FOREACH points GENERATE ST_MakePoint(lat, lon) AS point, time;
like it is found in some pigeon-tutorials.

Comment: Could you please tell me in which class you have this function written.

Comment: I loaded some points with points = 'Testpoints.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (X:double,Y:double,id:int,remark:chararray); and then wanted to use the pigeon-Funktion with s_points = FOREACH points GENERATE ST_MakePoint(X,Y) AS point,id,remark; Not sure in which class the function is written as I just use the JAR used in every tutorial like https://github.com/aseldawy/pigeon/blob/master/README.markdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st way:**

Call Syntax in Pig : `packagename.ClassName(arg0...)`

Source Code From Github :

```
    package edu.umn.cs.pigeon;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
    import org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray;
    import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

    import com.esri.core.geometry.Point;
    import com.esri.core.geometry.SpatialReference;
    import com.esri.core.geometry.ogc.OGCPoint;

    /**
     * @author Ahmed Eldawy
     *
     */

    public class MakePoint extends EvalFunc<DataByteArray> {

      @Override
      public DataByteArray exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input.size() != 2)
          throw new IOException("MakePoint takes two numerical arguments");
        double x = ESRIGeometryParser.parseDouble(input.get(0));
        double y = ESRIGeometryParser.parseDouble(input.get(1));
        Point point = new Point(x, y);
        OGCPoint ogc_point = new OGCPoint(point, SpatialReference.create(4326));
        return new DataByteArray(ogc_point.asBinary().array());
      }
    }
```

So syntax would be

```
FOREACH points GENERATE edu.umn.cs.pigeon.MakePoint(X,Y)
```

**2nd Way:**
**Use Short Function Names**

To avoid writing the full function name (package + class name), you can use the 'pigeon_import.pig' file that creates a short name for all functions. You can download the file [here](https://github.com/aseldawy/pigeon/blob/master/examples/pigeon_import.pig) and place it next to your Pigeon script. To load this file into your script, issue the following line to the beginning of your script.
IMPORT 'pigeon_import.pig';
After that, you can write the envelope function as ST_MakePoint instead of edu.umn.cs.pigeon.MakePoint

[Reference Blog](http://aseldawy.blogspot.in/2015/06/setting-up-pigeon-on-pig-and-hadoop.html)

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Cheers! Thats it! I didn't get it, cause here the pigeon_import.pig ist not mentioned, but used: https://github.com/aseldawy/pigeon/blob/master/README.markdown